# Multiple image upload approach laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

What's the best approach to store multiple images in database?

Upon browsing and searching for solution and approaches I found 2 options

`first one is take the file name and concatenate and separate them using either comma or |`
but I'm having doubts since I think that's messy and would produce errors later in the system

`second is I make another table for images and add foreign key (post_id) to know which post it belongs.`

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Just store your images as json. Perhaps under an ```images``` column, you can have ```{1: 'image1.png', 2: 'image2.png'}```

Comment: Go with #2 - It's the correct relational design. And laravel can handle those "hasMany" and "belongsTo" relations quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods work well. I would place the second.

It can also provide convenience when using some image upload plugins (filepond, dropzone etc.).

If I were to choose the first method, I would save the serialized arrays (with `serialize()`) for better bet.

Answer (score 1):

Second one because it is normalized and you can have a better DX with that, No weird implementation to edit or any manipulation of post.